# how can i show my minted NFT images on cardano testnet

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, nft, blockchain

**this my minted nft address**

> https://testnet.cardanoscan.io/transaction/38415ba47ba757b5ccb7240962fc064be56850b19f820e9a837aeed6e56e8081?tab=utxo

**Now i wants to show these minted NFT Images to any testnet marketplace if i want to create my own marketplace then how should i display my minted nfts there**

or is there anyway to show nfts images to wallet like solana wallet

Answer (score 2):

Also you can fetch all the assets in your wallet using the  BlockFrost Api https://blockfrost.io/, and then set the image src in you HTML to the corresponding IPFS URL.

Answer (score 1):

Adatools has a way to display minted NFTs on the Testnet:

https://testnet.adatools.io/nft

Answer (score 0):

Nami wallet can switch between testnet and mainnet in the settings:
[image]

And it also supports visualising your NFTs, though the NFTs I have aren't image files so Nami doesn't load them properly. If the NFT was minted with proper metadata, and contains an image, Nami will load the image from IPFS in place of the big "T" here:

[image]